# how to add image using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i have this code for navbar all works perfectly but when i try to replaced the text by an image the image does not displaying.

**here's the code:**

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="DAR.png" class="img-responsive"><b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Sign-in</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sign-up</a></li>
                                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a image inside link. check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27jsxjhy/1/). And make sure that path to the image is correct. If the path is right it should work. I changed your image and its working now.

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/pzvk4df07/1475139047_three_bars.png" class="img-responsive"><b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sign-in</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sign-up</a></li>
                            </ul>
```

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your trying to add an image to your navbar. If so you will need to add the image with css inside your nav. Remove your img link.  You can do this :

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="nav"data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sign-in</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sign-up</a></li>
                            </ul>
```

Inside your css add this :

```
#nav {
background-image:url('DAR.png');
}
```